# How to create smooth curvature in topology for a perfume bottle?

Tags: modeling

How can I model the body of and neck of the bottle as a connected object with clean topology?

[image: imagebottle]

Comment: i appreciate it very much

Answer (score 1):

For a good smooth shading you want the loops to distribute evenly, so a good starting point is a circle/cylinder that you can extrude and scale to fit the reference image:

[image]

Now you can use proportional editing to maintain smoothness of loop spacing:

[image]

Set Smooth shading, add subdivision modifier and add holding loops to control edges:

[image]

You probably should add the holding loops (3rd gif) first, and then use proportional editing (2nd gif), because otherwise the added loops position vertices at linear interpolation producing straight lines...

Comment: Really nice.. Are you editing .gifs for answers? If so, how?

Comment: @RobinBetts recently I started using https://ezgif.com/ to crop, optimize, scale gifs mostly to ensure they're below 2 MB, but also so that I don't have to worry too much about the recorded region, because I can crop when I'm done.